# jmeter getting error after providing correct css selector

Tags: css, jmeter, css-selectors

Css Selector expression not working in Jmeter

I am trying to create a Jmeter script using css selector extractor, but it always getting error.

Example from this page:
https://www.analog.com/en/about-adi/alliances/search.html?q=*

I want to extract each link in the result page, using the below css selector in Jmeter. I used the below css selector expression in Jmeter (Post Processors):

div.search-results-item div.col-md-8>h4>a

However, it always throwing the below error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 23: http://www.analog.com/${Alliances}
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone please help me. I tried everything to make it work but to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the error, looks like your variable is not evaluated: http://www.analog.com/${Alliances} . Check ${Alliances} variable properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that search results are basically not there, you can double check it yourself using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in HTML mode

[image]

In order to obtain the search results you need to execute another HTTP request:

[image]

So:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Add another HTTP Request sampler and configure it like:

   - Method: `POST`
   - Path: `https://www.analog.com/en/client/Search/PostAlliancesSearchResultsJson`
   - Request body:

     ```
     {
       "Facets": "FacetCategory:capabilities_sm,IsMultiSelect:true,IsAllRequired:false,FacetType: filter,IsPivot: false,ParentPivot:,IncludeZeroCount:false|FacetCategory:market_l1_fac_sm,IsMultiSelect:true,IsAllRequired:false,FacetType: filter,IsPivot: false,ParentPivot:,IncludeZeroCount:false|FacetCategory:prod_cat_l1_fac_sm,IsMultiSelect:false,IsAllRequired:false,FacetType: filter,IsPivot: false,ParentPivot:,IncludeZeroCount:false|FacetCategory:regions_sm,IsMultiSelect:true,IsAllRequired:false,FacetType: filter,IsPivot: false,ParentPivot:,IncludeZeroCount:false",
       "Filters": "",
       "Content": "*",
       "PageSize": 10,
       "PageStart": 0,
       "SortBy": "customdate_s",
       "Order": "relevancy"
     }
     ```
3. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the 2nd HTTP Request sampler and configure it to send [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) with the value of `application/json`
4. Add [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) as a child of the 2nd HTTP Request sampler and configure it like:

   - Name of created variables: `Alliance`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$..AbsoluteURL`
   - Match No: `-1`
5. That's it, now you should get the URLs you're looking for

   [image]

Comment: Thank you. I got it now. Solved the problem..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

- you set href in your css selector ?
- your css selector matches something using View Rests Tree and renderer Css Selector tester
- you have put your extractor on correct request
- you extract from text response and not another field

Because from your error, extraction has not matched anything